# Dynamic styling with XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

```
 G     G     G       B     B     B

 G     G     G       B     B     B

 G     G     G       B     B     B

 R     R     R       Y     Y     Y

 R     R     R       Y     Y     Y

 R     R     R       Y     Y     Y
```

All of the G B R and Y's above are the individual buttons that are created dynamically using DataTemplate and LIST, and they are arranged inside a WrapPanel. I want to add specific styles to the G, B, R, Y to form a matrixed button list like in the above example. Is there any method to do this using only XAML?

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CategoryPanel" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontFamily="Teuton Normal" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="1">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Button Height="55" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Teuton Normal" FontSize="12" Margin="1,1" Padding="3" Click="changeCategory">
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" FontFamily="Teuton Normal" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
             </Button>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Please show DataTemplate whcih generates such buttons

Comment: Please make question more clear, what is the problem?

Comment: It's highly advised to put the actual *question* first in the body so that the preview on the questions page is comprehensible/useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.triggers.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use triggers, which will be trggiered on the basis of specific value gets matched.